# Retore script for mysql db getting error

Tags: mysql

Hello I trying this code for restore script in ubuntu for restore db in mysql but in this code on do word getting error is "unexpected word do" please help me for this.

```
for f in test.sql.gz; 
  do
     db="${f%%.*}"
     echo "creating database $db"
     mysql -h localhost -u root -p mysql --password=passwd <<< "create database $db"
     echo "restoring database $db"
     gunzip "$f"
     mysql -h localhost -u root -ppasswd "$db" < "$db.sql"
  done
```

Comment: You should flag the question with `bash`, since bash gives the error. Why do you use a for-loop for a single file?

Comment: Weird... on bash I get "Syntax error: redirection unexpected". Using the -e flag at line 6 (mysql) seems to work. No error on "do". Do you have  correct shebang? (#!/bin/bash)

Comment: where is used this --> #!bin/bash.....starting on file right....